# INNER JOIN does not work for me

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I'm trying to make my SQL query work and I fail, so I decided to ask more experienced and familiar with SQL people since I'm not so.

What I have: 2 tables in my DB, one is "DEV" table that contains: `id, lat, lon, login, password` second one is "TASK" table which contains: `id, lat, lon, address, id_dev`. Id_dev is a foreign key to table "DEV".

What I'm trying to do is: Make query to get all DEVs that have NO task assigned (there is no record in table "task" with given dev.id) and get another list of DEVs that have tasks.

I want them separated. I tried something from a tutorial:

```
SELECT * FROM `dev` INNER JOIN 'task' ON dev.id=task.id_dev ORDER BY dev.id;
```

But it didn't work for me. Any suggestions please?
Kind regards!

Comment: "But it didn't work for me" - is that the best problem description? NO!

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `dev` INNER JOIN 'task' ON dev.id=task.id_dev ORDER BY dev.id' at line 1

Comment: what did you expect to happen and why? What did the tutorial say? did you look up what an inner join does so what you expect it to do?

Comment: provide alias to the database object and try again.

Comment: You need backticks, not single quotes around 'task' i.e. \`task\`

Comment: They were suggested by phpmyadmin, as I said before, I'm not familiar with this stuff. Thank you, I'll remember about quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the 'dev' records with no 'task' you shouldn't use `INNER JOIN` as that brings back the intersection of the sets.

One option is to use a `LEFT JOIN`, so something like:

```
SELECT      dev.* 

FROM        dev

LEFT JOIN   task
    ON      dev.id=task.id_dev 

WHERE       task.id_dev IS NULL

ORDER BY    dev.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, should have used left join for that. Works perfectly, thank you

Comment: I've got one additional question. I was just populating my DB and as I assigned more than 1 task for a single dev, I started getting clone records. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I figured out, it was only "DISTINCT" keyword. Sorry for mess

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `dev` INNER JOIN 'task' ON dev.id=task.id_dev ORDER BY dev.id;
```

Do not use single quote `'` on `task`. Query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `dev` INNER JOIN `task` ON dev.id=task.id_dev ORDER BY dev.id;
```

Comment: That still brings back the intersection of the two sets, not "all DEVs that have NO task assigned"

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM `dev` d 
LEFT JOIN `task` t ON d.id = t.id_dev 
WHERE t.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY d.id;
```